# Is there a way to identify, within a shader, the current GPU thread ID?

Tags: unity, shaders, multithreading, gpu

My question is rather simple: within a shader, is there a way (that works both in DirectX and OpenGL) to retrieve the ID of the given GPU thread being executed at the given iteration?

I am using Unity 5.3.4, if that helps. But I guess this is actually quite a platform-agnostic question. I have searched quite a bit for it, but found nothing satisfactory.

Comment: Why would you need to?

Comment: @ratchetfreak Hi there, thanks for commenting and sorry for being late to it. So, I need for a couple of things. The most urgent is better controlling random number generation within the shader. Is there a way to retrieve a thread ID?